# How to obtain conditional expectation and covariance?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If
$$Y = \begin{cases}X,\: X < 1/2,\\1/2,\: X \geq 1/2\end{cases}\quad X \sim U(0,1)$$

What would be $E(X|Y)$ and how to get $Cov(X,Y)$?

I've already scribbled many sheets, but the result doesn't match the template.

Comment: ("Esperança" is translated as "expectation" in English when discussing anything about probability or statistics.)  What does your "template" say?  How does your work not match it?

Comment: Also, "conditional expectation" is generally used in English for what you are calling "conditional hope" in the title, namely $E[X \mid Y]$.